# In on-demand resources, I can't get path of downloaded Images

Tags: ios, path, on-demand-resources

I implemented ODR to reduce bundle size and want to get path of downloaded resources, I can't get path. Also I get access of that image using UIImage, but my requirement is file path. Can anyone please help me in this?

I tried to access path after loading bundle but not able to access. I also try with getting URL but it also not working.

If I stored images directly in project I got that image path but In that case I can get only 1x Image.